# Scala flatMap function syntax with type parameter

Tags: scala

According to the API, function signature is `def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]` with B being the type of the element of the returned collection

then why doesn't 
`val xs = Map("a" -> List(11,111), "b" -> List(22,222)).flatMap[Int](_._2)` compile? It is giving a 'wrong number of type parameters for method' error, seems to suggest the signature is different to what is in the API doc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the signature given in the API docs is [intentionally wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132459/why-are-scaladoc-method-signatures-wrong), to conceal the implicit `CanBuildFrom` parameter because it upsets people. Click "Full Signature" at the bottom of the method documentation to see the actual signature:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: ((A, B)) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])
                    (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[A, B], B, That]): That
```

In this case, you can just leave off the type parameter.

```
scala> val xs = Map("a" -> List(11,111), "b" -> List(22,222)).flatMap(_._2)
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(11, 111, 22, 222)
```